# jQuery modal dialog with checkbox and link

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, submit, modal-dialog

Been trying to figure this out for days (trials of being a novice, me thinks!) so your help would be very welcome.

A jscript widget displays a Continue button. When user clicks the button I need a modal dialog to display a message (containing a hyperlink to an agreement doc) and a checkbox for the user to confirm they've read an agreement. After closing the dialog, if `checkbox = 0` then the Continue button opens the same dialog (loop, until checkbox is clicked: `checkbox = 1`).

Here's the code I've gathered together so far...

For the dialog:

```
<a href="#" id="sdHc3" rel="simpleDialog3">Click to open dialog</a>  
<span style="display:none;" id="checkboxStatus"></span>

<div style="display:none;" id="simpleDialog3">
    <h3>Terms and Conditions</h3>
    <form id="checkboxForm">
        Please check box to confirm that you have read the <a href="assets/docs/agreement.html">agreement</a>: <input type="checkbox" class="chckbx" value="1" />
    </form>
    <p><a href="#" class="close">Close</a></p>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#sdHc3').simpleDialog({
    showCloseLabel: false,
    open: function () {
        $('#checkboxStatus').html('');
    },
    close: function () {
        var c = [];
        $('#checkboxForm :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            c.push($(this).val());
        });
        $('#checkboxStatus').html('Checked ' + c.join(', ') + '.').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

and for detecting a click on the widget button:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
document.body.onmousedown = function (e) {
    var query = window.location;
    var anchor1=query.hash.substring(1); //anchor without the # character
    if( ($(event.target).hasClass("gwt-Button")) && (anchor1=="step3"))
    {
        alert("Widget button clicked");
    }
}
</script>
```

The 'dialog' code works ok and the widget button click detection code also works well. It's currently a mystery to me though how to bring these together and achieve the goal. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So when the widget button is clicked you need to see if the input is checked, and if not, show the dialog again like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // detect button click
    $('.gwt-Button').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1); // remove # character
        if (anchor != "step3") {
            return; // not step 3
        }
        if ($('#checkboxForm .chckbx').is(':checked')) {
            // checked
        }
        else {
            $('#sdHc3').click(); // trigger dialog again
        }
    });

    // setup dialog
    $('#sdHc3').simpleDialog({
        showCloseLabel: false,
        open: function () {
           $('#checkboxStatus').html('');
        },
        close: function () {
            var c = [];
            $('#checkboxForm :checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                c.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#checkboxStatus').html('Checked ' + c.join(', ') + '.').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Owlvark! Yes, that's the goal. Also, it'd be great if the "agreement" link opened in the/a dialog with confirmation checkbox. Can you suggest how to bring the code together?

Comment: I have suggested a replacement of the widget click detect code. As for the agreement link, I think you'd be best off using ajax to load the content when the link is clicked.

Comment: Thanks! I've replaced the widget click detect code with yours and left the 'dialog' section of code unchanged. 
Now the button click doesn't seem to be detected and the dialog doesn't appear.  I feel really lost with this - would appreciate any more input you can give.

Comment: I moved the dialog setup into _document ready_. If it still doesn't work, make sure your continue button has a class of `gwt-Button` and the url has `#step3` on the end.

Comment: Thanks again. I replaced all the code with yours to no avail. No errors in the Chrome console. Checked that 'Continue' button has a class of gwt-Button and the url has #step3 on the end.
Noticed that the 'Click to open dialog' link no longer worked too. So, pasted back in `$('#sdHc3').simpleDialog({ ... });` bit of code, as a separate script, and the dialog appeared when 'Click to open dialog' clicked. Any ideas very welcome!